# Javascript value if input html selected

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an input html `country`  and a script like this:

checkout.php Input html :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="country_shipping">Paese<sup>*</sup></label>
              <select class="form-control dark" id="country_ship" name="country_ship" tabindex="-1">

                    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                    .... with all countries
              </select>
            </div>
</div>
```

My FIRST script:

```
<script> 

    $('#country_ship').change(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "Italy" 

        )
      {
         $('#price_ship').val('<?php echo $Italy;?>'); // it work well
         $('data-amount').val('{{ $total * 100 - $price_coupon * 100 + $Italy * 100 }}'); // it doesnt work well
         $('#total_ship').val('<?php echo number_format($total - $price_coupon + $Italy, 2);?>');  // it work well
      }
   });
</script>
```

My SECOND Script (button stripe):

```
<script
                                    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                                    data-key="pk_test_yNuawoy0jUqj1GC14jwcQR5d"
                                    data-amount=""
                                    data-name="dixard"
                                    data-description="Widget"
                                    data-image="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stripe-uploads/acct_14s03fK9wMx3sd9Bmerchant-icon-1416180891533-icona.jpg"
                                    data-locale="auto"
                                    data-currency="eur"

                                    data-id="stripe"

                                    >
</script>
```

In my FIRST script i'm trying to give a value if user select country *Italy*, but it doesn't work! I would like attribute a value to "data-mount" with my operation.

maybe I'm wrong here:

```
$('data-amount').val('{{ $total * 100 - $price_coupon * 100 + $Italy * 100 }}');
```

my variables like $total, $price_coupon, $italy exist and return the right values. i'm using "{{" because i'm using laravel blade template.

Thank your for your help!

Comment: I hope your problem is solved, if not please tell any.

Answer (score 0):

`$('data-amount')` targets tag name.

if you want to target [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), use

```
$('[data-amount]')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use javascript to update the attribute `data-amount` value where the var `point_val` is the value which you want to assign.

```
document.querySelector("script").setAttribute("data-amount",point_val);
```